# Setting Tailwind Typography Default Header Font

Tags: tailwind-css

What is the best way to set all headers in my prose class to a specific font?

The following is what I have, but does not seem to be working:

```
theme: {
 typography: {
  DEFAULT: {
    css: {
      h1: {
        fontFamily: ['Bebas Neue', 'sans-serif'],
      },
      h2: {
        fontFamily: ['Bebas Neue', 'sans-serif'],
      },
      h3: {
        fontFamily: ['Bebas Neue', 'sans-serif'],
      },
      h4: {
        fontFamily: ['Bebas Neue', 'sans-serif'],
      },
      h5: {
        fontFamily: ['Bebas Neue', 'sans-serif'],
      },
...
```

Also is there a less verbose way to set all headers at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `prose-headings` variant or any other element [modifier](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/typography-plugin#element-modifiers) you need. Prose headings will target `h1, h2, h3, h4, th`

```html
<div class="prose prose-headings:text-red-400">
 // Content
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/gK0SO8Z1jz)

Comment: Oh Wow. I love tailwind!